# Is there a way to perform XSLT through 'XML Task' in Visual Studio in Azure Storage Account (BLOB)

Tags: xml, azure, xslt, ssis, blob

My questions concerns the following:

I have XML documents stored in an Azure Storage Account (BLOB).
I wish to transform these documents by applying XSLT (XML Task in Visual Studio - SSIS).
I wish to load these new documents in a separate container.

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 Pro. I was hoping to be able to configure it all in a SSIS package.
When selecting XSLT transformation my only input source options seem to be:

- Direct Input
- File Connection
- Variable

I was hoping for a Storage Connection, this does not seem to be possible.

Any advice on this topic? Should I not be configuring this in SSIS and in a different Azure service?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(1) SSIS XML Task accepts XML/XSLT file connections via HTTP protocol.

(2) Azure Logic App has Transform XML action.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-transform

Comment: Hi Yitzhak, thanks for commenting. Specifically, how would I go about using 'XML Task' to connect via HTTP protocol?